# sudo: /opt/lmapp/lampp: command not found

Tags: apache, lampp

I am trying to install lampp. But I am facing some problem about this. I am using ubuntu 16.04 and I used this command
`sudo apt-get install lamp-server^`

At the bottom of the terminal I am getting this

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 mysql-client-5.7 : Depends: mysql-common (>= 5.5)
 mysql-server-5.7 : PreDepends: mysql-common (>= 5.5)
                    Depends: mysql-common (>= 5.6.22-1~)
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

After installation when I try to start lampp server by `sudo /opt/lampp/lampp start`
I get this: `sudo: /opt/lmapp/lampp: command not found`

What should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Step 1 – Configure Apt Repository

```
wget http://repo.mysql.com/mysql-apt-config_0.8.9-1_all.deb
sudo dpkg -i mysql-apt-config_0.8.9-1_all.deb
```

Step 2- Install mysql Server
    sudo apt-get update
    sudo apt-get install mysql-server
Step 3- Secure Mysql installation

```
mysql_secure_installation
```

Install apache web server

```
sudo apt-get install apache2
```

Install PHP DO below Things
1. Add Repostitory command

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php
```

2. Update Packages
    sudo apt-get update
3. Install php 7.2

   sudo apt-get install php7.2
4. For php 5.6

   sudo apt-get install php5.6
5. Chekec Install php

   php -v